# Why my CartList is not working in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-http

after **add to cart** I find my **Cart list** empty in my flutter app. but in browser or postman when I hit **Cart List Api** after **add to cart api** it returns cart List. I am giving these two api below:

1. Add to cart: https://www.moharaj.com.bd/_public/addToCart?quantity=5&slug=cotton-fleece-hoodie-for-men-tekka-8486&variant_id=24469
   (The response I get: **{"status":"SUCCESS","message":"Cotton Fleece Hoodie For Men - Tekka add your cart"}**)
2. Cart List: https://www.moharaj.com.bd/_public/cartToContent
   (the response i get: **{"cart_total":"0.00","cart_content":[],"item_count":0}**

this is my **add to cart**  api http call:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AddToCartService {
  String addToCartStatus = "";
  Future<void> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "https://www.moharaj.com.bd/_public/addToCart?quantity=5&slug=cotton-fleece-hoodie-for-men-tekka-8486&variant_id=24469"));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
      addToCartStatus = response.body;
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
}
```

this is my **cart List** Api http call:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class CartToContentService {
  var cartListStatus = "";
  Future<void> getCartContent() async {
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse("https://www.moharaj.com.bd/_public/cartToContent"));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
      cartListStatus = response.body;
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
}
```

this is my homePage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:practice_dio/Cart/AddToCartService.dart';
import 'package:practice_dio/Cart/CartToContentService.dart';
import 'package:practice_dio/Cart/CheckOutService.dart';
import 'package:practice_dio/Login/Login.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  var cart = CartToContentService();

  var addCart = AddToCartService();

  String _addToCartStatus = "";
  String _cartListStatus = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Home Page")),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("Add To Cart Status: \n" + _addToCartStatus),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Text("Cart List Status: \n" + _cartListStatus),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  child: Text("Add To Cart"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _addToCartStatus = addCart.addToCartStatus;
                    });
                    addCart.getData();
                  }),
              MaterialButton(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Text("Cart List"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _cartListStatus = cart.cartListStatus;
                    });
                    cart.getCartContent();
                  }),                  
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where its working? in flutter app or browser??

Comment: Can you share full code

Comment: In App .........

Comment: I/flutter ( 6344): {"status":"SUCCESS","message":"Cotton Fleece Hoodie For Men - Tekka add your cart"}

Comment: I know this api works fine but when your call **cartList** cart list returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

class Item {

```
final double  quantity;
final String slag;
final int  variant_id;
Item({required quantity , required slag, required  variant_id});
Map<String  ,dynamic> toMap(Item item)=>{
'quantity': this.quantity,
'slag': this.slag,
'variant_id': this.variant_id

 }
```

}

```
why dont you use Post Verb?
// Create your  item Object 
Item _item = Item(5 , 'test',3);
call the service 
Service _service  = Service();
_service.AddItemToCard(_item.toMap());

 

Future<bool> AddItemTocard(Map<String, dynamic> item) async{
try{
    final _response  = await  http.post(Uri.parse(ApiBaseUrl), body: json.encode(item));`
  if(_response.statusCode == 200  || _response.statusCode == 201 )
    return true;
  else
    return false;
 }
catch(exception)
  {
   throw exception;
 }
}
```

Comment: its not an post method and I don't have problem in **add to cart** api. My problem is **cart List api**. its returning empty cart

Comment: try to convert json.decode(response.body);

Comment: Imran sifat see this code in github
https://github.com/MarioCarlosChita/answer_http

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).